# Поиск по List<T>

Tags: c#, list

Есть `List <StudSkills>`

```
    public class StudSkills
{
    public string Student { get; set; }
    public bool Math { get; set; }
    public bool Phisycs { get; set; }
}
```

Как получить количество строк, в которых Math = true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Думаю можно так

```
list.Count(item => item.Math)
```